# Combinations in C++

Tags: c++

Let's say you have a vector of strings that store an X at a spot specified by the user.  For example, the user can type "X 3", and you have to tell them if an X can be inserted at the 3rd position in the vector.  This is where the problem arises...telling the user if the insertion is valid.

So, basically, the vector has 2 numbers assigned to it that change every time the user runs the program.  So, let's say the vector size was 10 and the numbers assigned to it were 3, 2.  This means that there has to be exactly one run of 3 X's, at least one space, and one run of 2 X's.  So, it could look something like this:

> X X X _ _ _ _ X X _

In this case, if the user entered an X in any of the above positions where an X is, it would be a valid move.  But, the user could have also done something like this:

> _ _ _ _ X X X _ X X

And that would also be valid.

My question is: how do I set up a system that deals with all the possible combinations of the user input being valid?

Keep in mind that the vector size can be any size.  This problem is actually part of a picross puzzle, in case that helps!

Comment: And what did you try so far? Any code you can share with us?

Comment: What do you mean with having to deal with all the possible combinations of the user input "being valid"?

Comment: @Bart I don't have any code, I've really just been trying to think of this conceptually, and I've had trouble finding any way to really start

Comment: You'll get a warmer reception on SO if you present some evidence that you've had a crack at it yourself, or at least given it some thought.

Comment: @leo A user's input is valid if it "works" with the information.  So if the vector size was 10, and the numbers were 3 and 2, an X can be inserted in a whole bunch of ways, 2 of such ways I've drawn in my question

Comment: @MarceloCantos the only real "crack" at the problem I've had was trying to establish mathematical formulas that could generalize the problem.  But, I don't know how I'd work those into code...

Comment: Ehm, you'll need one space between every run, so you need n-1 spaces. Every run has a size, so the minimum number of spaces you need is the sum of all runs + n -1.
Does this answer your question? or you actually want the number of combinations?

Comment: @leo, I'm not sure what you mean.  I need a system to check if the position the position a user enters an X in is a valid position.

So, let's say the vector size was 7 and the numbers were 1 and 2:

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1, 2

If the user wants to enter an X, say, in the 5th position:

_ _ _ _ _ X _

This move would be valid because we can configure the vector:

_ X _ _ _ X X

Or any other possible way it works

Comment: So you have as input 2 numbers (representing 2 separate runs of X) and  a position p, and you want to know if it's possible to arrange the runs of X's in a way that one of the runs' X's is in p?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  Along with that, it also has to be the case that the two runs can exist in the vector given the position p...which is kind of the same thing.

Comment: Well, given this configuration, the only impossible situation is when both runs have the same size, which is half of the (size of the vector -1), and the index you choose is exactly in the middle. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: This isn't true.  Let's say the vector size was 10, and the numbers were 1 and 2.

Let's say the user enters two X's at these positions:

X _ _ _ _ _ _ X _ _

Now, we would say that the user's 3rd X HAS to come either one position after, or one position before the 2nd X. Anywhere else that the user enters an X would make the move invalid.  Get it?

Comment: Ok, so the user sets the positions of everything. Why don't you just create a vector and simulate it as the user enters the data?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't think I get your problem. I just suggested you to try implementing it the simplest (stupidest) way you can.

Answer (score 1):

The following function generates permutations of the spaces between segments, returning false when it can't generate any more:

```
template <typename SpaceIter>
bool next(SpaceIter start, SpaceIter finish)
{
  for (SpaceIter i = start; i != finish; ++i)
    {
      // Find the first non-minimised space.
      if (*i)
        {
          SpaceIter j = i; ++j;
          if (j == finish)
            return false;

          int s = *i;  // Remember *i, in case i == start.

                                // Preserve the invariant: Σ(space[i])
                                //        i != start  i == start
                                //        ----------  -----------
          // Minimise current.
          *i = 0;               // Gain =   -s        overwritten
          // Increment the next.
          ++*j;                 // Gain =        1         1
          // Adjust the first.
          *start = s - 1;       // Gain =    s - 1        -1
                                //        -----------------------
                                // Nett =      0           0
          return true;
        }
    }
  return false;
}
```

Note that this algorithm requires inclusion of the spaces at the ends and works on *excess* space — i.e., a space of length S is represented as S if it's at either end, but as S - 1 if it's somewhere in the middle, since interior spaces must be of length one or greater. Just to be clear, in this representation, all spaces have a minimum value of zero. You initialise `spaces` by setting the first space to N + 1 - Σ<sub>i = 0..N</sub>(length<sub>i</sub> + 1) and the remaining N + 1 spaces to 0, where N is the number of sequences.

To complete the story, you need to test whether any given permutation of spaces, combined with the array of lengths, is compatible with a given input.

A simple approach is to convert the input into a bitset at the start. Then transform each spaces permutation together with the lengths array into a bitset and subtract from the input bitset. If the result is empty, the input is valid.

**Caveat:** I analysed the above algorithm fairly carefully, but I've have done very little testing of the code. Here's a rather grotty test driver I wrote, in case it helps with your own testing:

```
template <typename T, int N>
bool next(T (&spaces)[N])
{
  return next(spaces, spaces + N);
}

const char* x(int n) { return "XXXXXXXXXX" + 10 - n; }
const char* s(int n) { return "----------" + 10 - n; }

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  int spaces[] = { 4, 0, 0, 0 };
  do
    {
      // I reverse the spaces to make segments shuffle left-to-right.
      // This is a purely aesthetic thing. The order of permutations
      // doesn't matter.
      std::cout << s(spaces[3]) << x(2)
                << s(spaces[2] + 1) << x(1)
                << s(spaces[1] + 1) << x(1)
                << s(spaces[0])
                << "\n";
    }
  while (next(spaces));
}
```